# C++ remove() and rename() gives "Permission error"

Tags: c++

I can't figure out what is happening in my program, it's a simple function to clear all the Windows '\r' from a file, putting all the chars in another file and then rename it to substitute the old file. Every time I execute the function the rename() and remove() functions give me "Permission error" even if I had all the file pointers closed and the file on my PC is closed in every program. Here's the code

```
static bool correctFile(string fileName) {
        string name = fileName;
        FILE* test = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "rb");
        FILE *in, *out;
        char stringTest[1000];
        bool isWinFile = false;
        if (!test) {
            return false;
        }
        fread(stringTest, 1, 1000, test);
        fclose(test);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(stringTest) && !isWinFile; i++) {
            if (stringTest[i] == '\r') {
                isWinFile = true;
            }
        }
        if (isWinFile) {
            in = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "rb");
            string tempFile = name + ".temp";
            out = fopen(tempFile.c_str(), "wb");
            if (!in || !out) {
                return false;
            }
            char temp;
            while (fread(&temp, sizeof(temp), 1, in) > 0) {
                if (temp != '\r') {
                    fwrite(&temp, sizeof(temp), 1, out);
                }
            }
            fclose(in);
            fclose(out);
            if (std::remove(fileName.c_str())) {
                std::cerr << "Error: " << strerror(errno);
                return false;
            }
            if (std::rename(tempFile.c_str(), fileName.c_str())) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

If you find an error in this please tell me, thanks

Comment: Could your problem be your antivirus?

Comment: I already disabled it

Comment: Talking about Permission Error, what is your OS? If Linux or macOS, did you try `sudo` like `sudo ./a.out`? If Windows, did you try Run as Administrator?

Comment: It works for me. The problem is likely outside this piece of code.

Comment: It works with MacOS, even Ubuntu but not windows, I heard about folders permissions but I tried it on my desktop, that has write and read permissions

Comment: Maybe try providing the actual error message shown for us to help

Comment: Error: "Permission denied" (from errno)

Comment: On Windows, try reporting the value returned by `GetLastError` rather than `errno`.  It is more expressive.

Comment: Is there no error number? It is supposed to show a number, for instance errno=13 or something

Comment: not an error, but calling `strlen(stringTest)` inside a for loop is extremely bad. Store the length in a variable and reuse instead

Comment: Did the Run as administrator option worked?

Comment: errno = 13, GetLastError() = 2, Admin execution doesn't work

Comment: If its errno=13, it's definitely file read permission issues. Since you said you disabled antivirus and it didn't change, might as well try chmod or chownto modify the permission on the file, not where it is

Comment: _errno = 13, GetLastError() = 2_ does not compute.  Make sure you call `GetLastError` _immediately_ after the call that fails, and code it as `auto err = GetLastError (); std::cout << err;` so that it doesn't get overwritten before you have a chance to print it out.  It doesn't stick around for long.

Comment: GetLastError() gives me code 32

Comment: Well code 32 is the "another process is using the file" but I don't know what process is using it if it's all closed

Comment: Maybe the tools here like this: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) may help you figure out were this file is open.

Comment: @Jg_747 If the issue is "permission denied", why post so much code to show this error?  A simple 3 line function that attempts to open the file is all you need.  As a matter of fact, that is the first thing you should have done -- remove *all* the irrelevant code, and simply attempt to open the file, and preferably one with a hardcoded name (and not hidden behind a `std::string` variable).  Posting so much code indicates you didn't do enough research on your own to determine the error.

Comment: _if (!in || !out) return false;_ potentially leaking a file handle there, and if a previous call to this function left a file open then that might explain this.  Solution: better error handling.

Comment: If you used ifstream and ofstream they would have closed the file for you in that case (of bad error handling described in the previous comment) in the destructor. The `c` file functions will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the old file and the new file **must not** be in the same folder for some reason

Comment: Are you doing this on a network share ?I remember seeing this issue ,long ago, XP-times. At some point, I decided to rename both files, not delete the source files right away, but afterward.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Disable the virus scanner and see if the problem persists. Some antivirus products block access to files for a couple of microseconds after they have been written or modified. I know of Kaspersky for example.

I have a "Antivirus" retry loop in some of my batch files because of this. So one (ugly) solution is to retry the rename/remove operations a couple of times.